# How to add a bit in a short int

Tags: int, bit, short

I'm having trouble putting a 1 bit at a given position.
For example if ***int e*** is one, I have put the first bit in **neset_t* ne**  to 1.

I've done this so far but does not work.

```
typedef unsigned short int neset_t;

    void add(neset_t* ne,int e){

    int num = (int) *ne;
    num = num | e;
    *ne = (neset_t) num;
}
```

thanks in advance.
sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is e is bit position? 
In this case you should use

> num = num | (1 << e);

instead

> num = num | e;

Answer (score 0):

If e is the bit position you should do `num |= (1 << e)`